# Windows 7 firewall: how to block all connections except one application?

Tags: windows-7, networking, security, firewall, teamviewer

I need help in setting up a firewall on Windows 7 Home Edition.
I want to block all traffic – inbound and outbound for everything except one application: TeamViewer.exe

To accomplish this, I have created 2 inbound rules:

1. Allow the connection for this program C:\Program Files
   (x86)\TeamViewer\TeamViewer.exe

   - Computers: Authorized computers and Exceptions are unchecked;
   - Advanced: All profiles; All Interface Types; Block edge traversal;
   - Scope: Any IP Local or remote;
   - Protocols: Any;
2. Allow the connection for this program C:\Program Files
   (x86)\TeamViewer\TeamViewer_Service.exe.exe

   - Everything else is the same as in rule 1;

Also I have created 2 outbound rules identical to the inbound rules.

I have checked that no active “Block the connection” rules exit in both inbound and outbound folders.

All default rules stay intact.

Finally I opened “Windows Firewall Properties” and Outbound connections to “Block” on Domain, Private and Public profiles tabs. 
I have clicked Apply and immediately lost connection to TeamViewer.
After reboot, TeamViewer on another machine shows this computer status “Offline”.

I had to revert Outbound connections to “Allow”.
What am I doing wrong? How can I setup Windows 7 firewall to block all connections except one application (TeamViewer)?

Please note the computer has Windows 7 Home Edition installed and does not have Group Policy Editor.

Comment: You can not. If you block all exe file then it will include the svchost.exe which also responsible for DNS queries. You can use [Glasswire](https://www.glasswire.com/) to manage network activity easily.

Comment: Thanks. I've spent a lot of time trying make it work. But aren't default rules intended to allow minimal necessary network connections?

Comment: Yes. But your blocking those (when you lost the connection). I am not sure why the tight security but arguably outbound connections are generally less hazardous than inbound. Malicious applications often require 2 way communication (some odd application that only sends data is possible though, of course).